# ¿Alguien sabe generar Excel con SQL Server parámetros de entradas?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy realizando un reporte con un procedimiento almacenado que tiene como entradas 3 entras uno es el monto, fecha,opcion.y en mi pagina tiene 3 input entradas para que ingrese y cuando presione exportar se baje un archivo excel el problema es que me muestra un error "COMO LA IMAGEN PORFAVOR [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]. Quisiera que me ayuden Porfavor

```
 protected void ExportExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;
           string query = "COMISION_DIC16";


            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {


                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("TP", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = txtTC.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("Fecha_FDM", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = txtFecha_FDM.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("OPC", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = OPC.SelectedItem.Value;


                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;


                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;


                        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(ds);

                            //Set Name of DataTables.
                            ds.Tables[0].TableName = "idcredito";
                            [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]



                            using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
                            {
                                foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
                                {
                                    //Add DataTable as Worksheet.
                                    wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
                                }

                                //Export the Excel file.
                                Response.Clear();
                                Response.Buffer = true;
                                Response.Charset = "";
                                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Cuadro_1_dic16.xlsx");
                                using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                                {
                                    wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                                    MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                                    Response.Flush();
                                    Response.End();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Aparentemente el stored procedure `COMISION_DIC16` no existe. ¿Seguro escribistes bien el nombre del stored procedure?

Comment: @sstan Muchas gracias por responder si lo tengo creado pero como viste la imagen me vota de color rojo sda.fill(ds)  porque cuando solo un select prueba from prueba en ves del sp y en ves de los parametros si me sale pero con el store procedure me vota ese error

Comment: Verifica también que el usuario que estas usando en la cadena de conexión tenga permisos para ejecutar el procedimiento almacenado dentro de SQL Server.

Comment: ¿Seguro que el stored procedure no está definido en un esquema distinto a `dbo`? ¿Seguro estás apuntando al database correcto? Si quieres, como prueba, puedes cambiar el `CommandType` a `Text` y usar la forma más completa y explícita de ejecutar el stored procedure: `string query = "exec COMISION_DIC16 @TP, @Fecha_FDM, @OPC"` y ver que pasa. ¿Puedes ejecutar el stored procedure manualmente en SSMS y asegurarte que funciona bien desde allí?

Comment: Como nota aparte...este código no respeta la arquitectura MVC...porque estás mezclando base de datos, modelo, vista todo en un solo método.

Comment: si claro estoy apuntando mi conexion es asi
 <add name="con"  connectionString="server=192.168.105.150\SQL2012; database=Credito_Dic16; 


pero me sale que que no existe ese procedimiento pero si figura en mi base  de datos hasta ejecuta en mi sql server

Comment: Me sale este error Debe declarar la variable escalar "@TP".

Comment: @Pierro: ¿Cambió el error? ¿Qué probastes exactamente para que resultara en el cambio?

Comment: @sstan             Si en Microsoft store procedure en Uno de Mis parametros decia TC y en el visual lo puse Td por eso pero le cambie como el procedure su nombre y sale que el proc No existe
 lo voy editar como le puesto

Comment: ¿Podrias mostrar el código del stored?, y también intentar ejecutarlo desde la BD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucion :

```
  protected void ExportExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string query = "Rpt_Refinanciado"; //"COMISION"

        using (  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ObtenerCadenaConexion()))
        {


            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 90000000;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("f_ini", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtFecha_Ini.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("f_fin", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txt_Fecha_Fin.Text;
             // cmd.Parameters.Add("OPC", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = OPC.SelectedItem.Value;



                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;


                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

                    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(ds);

                        //Set Name of DataTables.
                        ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Rpt-Comision";



                        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
                        {
                            foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
                            {
                                //Add DataTable as Worksheet.
                                wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
                            }

                            //Export the Excel file.
                            Response.Clear();
                            Response.Buffer = true;
                            Response.Charset = "";
                            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Reporte_Comision.xlsx");

                            using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                                MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                                Response.Flush();
                                Response.End();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```